# SQL Server 2005 - Combine two datasets, but output a row even on non-matching

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I ask for your kind expertise on this issue.

Basically I need to combine two datasets, on matching fields, however, where there is no matching record in table1 against table2, the output table must include a value in a vote field to indicate it has not been missed off with a value of 0.

The scenario this applies to, is a voting system.  Three tables ELECTIONS, CANDIDATES and VOTES.

The final output table must output all the positions in the ELECTIONS table where there is a CANDIDATE.  However, there may not be any votes in the VOTES table for them for all the candidates for a position.  The output still must return the position, and a 0 against the VOTE.  The Code I have is this so far.

```
CREATE TABLE  #MYELECTIONS (E_POSITION_CODE INT, E_POSITIONNAME VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO #MYELECTIONS VALUES (147,'Manager')
INSERT INTO #MYELECTIONS VALUES (148,'Supervisor')
INSERT INTO #MYELECTIONS VALUES (149,'Counciler')

CREATE TABLE  #MYCANDIDATES (C_CANDIDATE_CODE INT, C_CANDIDATENAME VARCHAR (50), C_POSITION_CODE INT)

INSERT INTO #MYCANDIDATES VALUES (100,'Tom Cruise', 147)
INSERT INTO #MYCANDIDATES VALUES (101,'Micky Mouse', 147)
INSERT INTO #MYCANDIDATES VALUES (103,'Donald Duck', 147)
INSERT INTO #MYCANDIDATES VALUES (100,'Tom Cruise', 148)

CREATE TABLE  #MYVOTES (V_POSITION_CODE INT, V_CANDIDATE_CODE INT, V_VOTER VARCHAR(8), V_VOTINGPREFERENCE SMALLINT)

INSERT INTO #MYVOTES VALUES (147,100,'11111111',1)
INSERT INTO #MYVOTES VALUES (147,101,'11111111',2)
INSERT INTO #MYVOTES VALUES (147,103,'11111111',3)
INSERT INTO #MYVOTES VALUES (147,100,'22222222',1)
INSERT INTO #MYVOTES VALUES (147,100,'33333333',1)
INSERT INTO #MYVOTES VALUES (147,100,'44444444',1)
INSERT INTO #MYVOTES VALUES (147,101,'55555555',2)
INSERT INTO #MYVOTES VALUES (147,101,'66666666',1)
INSERT INTO #MYVOTES VALUES (147,103,'77777777',1)
INSERT INTO #MYVOTES VALUES (148,100,'88888888',1)
INSERT INTO #MYVOTES VALUES (148,100,'99999999',2)


DECLARE @MyPositionCode AS INT
    SET @MyPositionCode = 147

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @TEMPTABLE1 TABLE (T1_POSITIONCODE VARCHAR(3), T1_POSITIONNAME VARCHAR(255), 
        T1_CANDIDATECODE VARCHAR(8),T1_CANDIDATENAME VARCHAR(255))

INSERT INTO @TEMPTABLE1
SELECT 
E_POSITION_CODE,
E_POSITIONNAME,
C_CANDIDATE_CODE,
C_CANDIDATENAME

FROM #MYELECTIONS 
    INNER JOIN #MYCANDIDATES ON 
                E_POSITION_CODE = C_POSITION_CODE


WHERE #MYELECTIONS.E_POSITION_CODE = @MYPOSITIONCODE

SELECT * FROM @TEMPTABLE1

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @TEMPTABLE2 TABLE (T2_POSITIONCODE VARCHAR(3), T2_CANDIDATECODE VARCHAR(8), 
        T2_VOTE SMALLINT, T2_VOTER VARCHAR(8))

INSERT INTO @TEMPTABLE2
SELECT
V_POSITION_CODE,
V_CANDIDATE_CODE,
ISNULL(V_VOTINGPREFERENCE,0) AS 'VOTES',
V_VOTER

FROM #MYVOTES  
        LEFT OUTER JOIN @TEMPTABLE1 ON  
                    T1_POSITIONCODE = V_POSITION_CODE AND
                    T1_CANDIDATECODE = V_CANDIDATE_CODE


SELECT * FROM @TEMPTABLE2
```

The final output should be like this:

```
T1_POSITION_CODE    T1_POSITIONNAME T1_CANDIDATECODE    T1_CANDIDATENAME    T2_VOTER    T2_VOTE
147                 Manager         100                 Tom Cruise          11111111    1
147                 Manager         101                 Micky Mouse         11111111    2
147                 Manager         103                 Donald Duck         11111111    3
147                 Manager         100                 Tom Cruise          22222222    1
147                 Manager         101                 Micky Mouse         22222222    0
147                 Manager         103                 Donald Duck         22222222    0
147                 Manager         100                 Tom Cruise          33333333    1
147                 Manager         101                 Micky Mouse         33333333    0
147                 Manager         103                 Donald Duck         33333333    0
147                 Manager         100                 Tom Cruise          44444444    1
147                 Manager         101                 Micky Mouse         44444444    0
147                 Manager         103                 Donald Duck         44444444    0
147                 Manager         100                 Tom Cruise          55555555    0
147                 Manager         101                 Micky Mouse         55555555    2
147                 Manager         103                 Donald Duck         55555555    0
147                 Manager         100                 Tom Cruise          66666666    1
147                 Manager         101                 Micky Mouse         66666666    0
147                 Manager         103                 Donald Duck         66666666    0
147                 Manager         100                 Tom Cruise          77777777    0
147                 Manager         101                 Micky Mouse         77777777    0
147                 Manager         103                 Donald Duck         77777777    1
147                 Manager         100                 Tom Cruise          88888888    1
147                 Manager         101                 Micky Mouse         88888888    0
147                 Manager         103                 Donald Duck         88888888    0
147                 Manager         100                 Tom Cruise          99999999    2
147                 Manager         101                 Micky Mouse         99999999    0
147                 Manager         103                 Donald Duck         99999999    0
```

So, we can see 0 being returned against the positions in the votes column, that there are candidates for, even though the voter has not voted for them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why `147, 100, Tom Cruise, 99999999` is `2` here. I think it should be `0`. And this applies to last several voters.

Try something like:

```
CREATE TABLE  #MYELECTIONS (E_POSITION_CODE INT, E_POSITIONNAME VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO #MYELECTIONS VALUES (147,'Manager')
INSERT INTO #MYELECTIONS VALUES (148,'Supervisor')
INSERT INTO #MYELECTIONS VALUES (149,'Counciler')

CREATE TABLE  #MYCANDIDATES (C_CANDIDATE_CODE INT, C_CANDIDATENAME VARCHAR (50), C_POSITION_CODE INT)

INSERT INTO #MYCANDIDATES VALUES (100,'Tom Cruise', 147)
INSERT INTO #MYCANDIDATES VALUES (101,'Micky Mouse', 147)
INSERT INTO #MYCANDIDATES VALUES (103,'Donald Duck', 147)
INSERT INTO #MYCANDIDATES VALUES (100,'Tom Cruise', 148)

CREATE TABLE  #MYVOTES (V_POSITION_CODE INT, V_CANDIDATE_CODE INT, V_VOTER VARCHAR(8), V_VOTINGPREFERENCE SMALLINT)

INSERT INTO #MYVOTES VALUES (147,100,'11111111',1)
INSERT INTO #MYVOTES VALUES (147,101,'11111111',2)
INSERT INTO #MYVOTES VALUES (147,103,'11111111',3)
INSERT INTO #MYVOTES VALUES (147,100,'22222222',1)
INSERT INTO #MYVOTES VALUES (147,100,'33333333',1)
INSERT INTO #MYVOTES VALUES (147,100,'44444444',1)
INSERT INTO #MYVOTES VALUES (147,101,'55555555',2)
INSERT INTO #MYVOTES VALUES (147,101,'66666666',1)
INSERT INTO #MYVOTES VALUES (147,103,'77777777',1)
INSERT INTO #MYVOTES VALUES (148,100,'88888888',1)
INSERT INTO #MYVOTES VALUES (148,100,'99999999',2)


DECLARE @MyPositionCode AS INT = 147

SELECT  me.E_POSITION_CODE ,
        me.E_POSITIONNAME ,
        mc.C_CANDIDATE_CODE ,
        mc.C_CANDIDATENAME ,
        c.V_VOTER ,
        ISNULL(mv.V_VOTINGPREFERENCE, 0) AS V_VOTINGPREFERENCE
FROM    #MYCANDIDATES mc
        JOIN #MYELECTIONS me ON mc.C_POSITION_CODE = me.E_POSITION_CODE
        CROSS JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT
                            V_VOTER
                     FROM   #MYVOTES
                   ) c
        LEFT JOIN #MYVOTES mv ON mc.C_POSITION_CODE = mv.V_POSITION_CODE
                                 AND mc.C_CANDIDATE_CODE = mv.V_CANDIDATE_CODE
                                 AND c.V_VOTER = mv.V_VOTER
WHERE   mc.C_POSITION_CODE = @MyPositionCode
ORDER BY c.V_VOTER , C_CANDIDATE_CODE   

DROP TABLE #MYCANDIDATES
DROP TABLE #MYVOTES
DROP TABLE #MYELECTIONS
```

Output:

```
147 Manager 100 Tom Cruise  11111111    1
147 Manager 101 Micky Mouse 11111111    2
147 Manager 103 Donald Duck 11111111    3
147 Manager 100 Tom Cruise  22222222    1
147 Manager 101 Micky Mouse 22222222    0
147 Manager 103 Donald Duck 22222222    0
147 Manager 100 Tom Cruise  33333333    1
147 Manager 101 Micky Mouse 33333333    0
147 Manager 103 Donald Duck 33333333    0
147 Manager 100 Tom Cruise  44444444    1
147 Manager 101 Micky Mouse 44444444    0
147 Manager 103 Donald Duck 44444444    0
147 Manager 100 Tom Cruise  55555555    0
147 Manager 101 Micky Mouse 55555555    2
147 Manager 103 Donald Duck 55555555    0
147 Manager 100 Tom Cruise  66666666    0
147 Manager 101 Micky Mouse 66666666    1
147 Manager 103 Donald Duck 66666666    0
147 Manager 100 Tom Cruise  77777777    0
147 Manager 101 Micky Mouse 77777777    0
147 Manager 103 Donald Duck 77777777    1
147 Manager 100 Tom Cruise  88888888    0
147 Manager 101 Micky Mouse 88888888    0
147 Manager 103 Donald Duck 88888888    0
147 Manager 100 Tom Cruise  99999999    0
147 Manager 101 Micky Mouse 99999999    0
147 Manager 103 Donald Duck 99999999    0
```

Comment: Giorgi, the vote should be left as is, it is not a total.  So if there is a 2 as the value, then that is what should be reported back.

Comment: @user154550, I don't understand. You have
`INSERT INTO #MYVOTES VALUES (148,100,'99999999',2)`
Notice 148 here. And you are filtering by 147. Then why you want to show `147, 9999999, 2`?

Comment: I don't. I was responding to your original query in the reply. "I don't know why 147, 100, Tom Cruise, 99999999 is 2 here. I think it should be 0. And this applies to last several voters."  I am just indicating that the votes should be left as is.

Comment: Does my post answers your question? If not then why?

Comment: Yes, thanks Giorgi that works great! I realise I hand-typed some of the desired output, and gotten some of the values in the wrong order, appologies for that! Thanks for your help! :)